# Set config file on Rubocop Sublime Linter

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublimelinter, rubocop

I'm using Rubocop alongside SublimeLinter and we also included it on our continuous integration server, so there is a rubocop.yml on the root of our project.

The file in the root is the one the CI uses to validate the code, but it is not as strict as I want it to be in Sublime.

Is there a way to specify the yml file that I want Rubocop to use in Sublime?

Answer (score 2):

You can set rules in your .rubocop.yml file so sublimelinter works to your new style or if you wish to update the config path use

```
"rubocop": {
"args": ["--config", "path/to/config.yml"]}
```